# jQuery Appended button click event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery, I have a button click event which works well but when i use the append() to append the button inside div. The click event doesn't work

My code below:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    alert('works');
    $('#element').show("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use [jQuery event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):-

```
$(document).on('click', "#button", function() {
  alert('works');
  $('#element').show("slow");
});
```

Working example:-

```js
$('#append_button_dynamically').append("<button id='button'>ClickMe</button>");

$(document).on('click', "#button", function() {
  alert('works');
  $('#element').show("slow");
});
```

```css
#element{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="append_button_dynamically"></div>

<div id="element">This is hide but will show on button click</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Because the button is dynamically created, it cannot be triggered by “itself”, instead, trigger it through a static element, such as `<body>` :

```
$('body').on('click', '#button', function() {
    alert('works');
    $('#element').show("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code must work. You might have forgotten to include the `JQuery` file. Check the attached code snippet.

```js
$('#container').append("<button id='button'>Button</button>");
$('#button').click(function() {
    alert('works');
    $('#element').show("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>Button here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely doing that before the element exists in the DOM. You should probably have your scripts right before the `</body>` instead of in the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add few lines there!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button').click(function() {
          alert('works');
          $('#element').show("slow");
     });
});
```